# How to deploy an ear file in jboss using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jboss, ear

I wanted to deploy an ear project in to jboss using eclipse Helios. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed jboss tools plugin from http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_2
It takes care of the deployment in to the jboss server.

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse setup JBoss as a Server:  File -> New -> Other -> Server

Then right-click on the top-level project name of your ear and select Run As -> 1 Run On Server

Comment: This is to run the server. It'll not be deployed.

Comment: That will run .war web application projects (and others maybe) but not ear projects.